# How can I create a new view from a table and a flag int field of another table (with possibility of filtering)?

Tags: mysql, view

I have a table MODULES (with a  total of 60 modules)

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |

and the table EVENTS (with a ton more columns, but unnecessary for the question)

| ID | MODULES_USED |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 15 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 3 |

Table EVENTS has couple million rows.

The value of MODULES.ID represents the bit position of the module in the MODULES_USED integer (staring at 0), so, 15 in binary is 1111 which means modules 0, 1, 2 and 3 have been used. The same way, a value of MODULES_USED of 3 means 0011 which means modules 0 and 1 have been used. As well, 1 means 0001 (module 0) and 8 means 0100 (module 2).

And I need an output view MODULES_USED (so I i can create a column graph) as follows:

| ID | NAME | TIMES_USED |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 3 |
| 1 | B | 2 |
| 2 | C | 1 |
| 3 | D | 2 |

What I want to achieve is a report on the table MODULES_USED where the end user can filter by other columns of the EVENTS table (ID_COUNTRY,ID_PRODUCT...).

A possible solution that I've tried is a view with the following SQL query

```
SELECT
    `MODULES`.`ID` AS `ID`,
    `MODULES`.`NAME` AS `NAME`,
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT(`EVENTS`.`MODULES_USED`)
    FROM
        `EVENTS`
    WHERE
        (
            (
                `EVENTS`.`MODULES_USED` > 0
            ) AND(
                (
                    FLOOR(
                        (
                            `EVENTS`.`MODULES_USED` / POW(2, `MODULES`.`ID`)
                        )
                    ) % 2
                ) > 0
            )
        )
) AS `TIMES_USED`,
FROM
    `MODULES`
```

But this has 2 main issues:

It's very slow

Does not allow filtering out events unless modifying the view, for example if I want to filter by ID_PRODUCT (another field in EVENTS), I i have to edit the VIEW to add the ID_PRODUCT = 1 in the WHERE, which isn't so useful for the users of the report. Another approach is to create extra columns in the view with different filter criteria (one column for TOTAL, one column for each product, one column for each country, one column for each combination of product and country... ending up with hundreds of columns and hours to execute (i killed it before end).

A different approach I've thought of is to create a view of the EVENTS table where I add a column for each module, but aside from being 60 as of now it could be increased to hundreds in the future, so I don't know how to do that automatically/programmatically and how to combine that afterwards in a view that is transposed.

Comment: How slow is _"very slow"_? A full table scan of _"couple million rows"_ is always going to be relatively _"slow"_. `EVENTS.MODULES_USED & POW(2, MODULES.ID)` should be a little bit quicker than your current join, and `INNER JOIN ... GROUP BY` _may_ be quicker than your correlated subquery. I think you can add optional parameters to your queries with something like `(@param IS NULL OR ID_PRODUCT = @param)`.

Comment: @user1191247 correct, edited so its 3, 2, 1, 2

Comment: Querying serialized data is always going to be expensive as it is non-sargable. How many distinct values are there in `MODULES_USED`? It must be only a tiny fraction of the total number of possible combinations (2^60), as you have only _"couple million rows"_.

Comment: @user1191247 There are 577 distinct MODULES_USED values in EVENTS table

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is possible to achieve what you need with a view. And, I am not sure why you would want to.

Start by moving the aggregation into a derived table:

```sql
SELECT m.ID, m.NAME, IFNULL(SUM(e.num), 0) AS TIMES_USED
FROM MODULES m
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MODULES_USED, COUNT(*) AS num
    FROM `EVENTS`
    GROUP BY MODULES_USED
) e ON e.MODULES_USED & POW(2, m.ID)
GROUP BY m.ID;
```

This should perform significantly better, even without an index on `EVENTS.MODULES_USED`. When adding the filters (`ID_COUNTRY`, `ID_PRODUCT`, etc) to the inner query, ideally you want an index covering the filter conditions and ending with `MODULES_USED` to satisfy the `GROUP BY`. Adding indices to satisfy every possible combination is obviously not feasible, so you will need to figure out what the most important use cases are.

Comment: Thank you! Its a tad faster now, still slow, but... no easy solution to the problem unless i inject a service in between.